# Preview page on link hover

Tags: html, asp.net, hyperlink, popup, hover

Quick question:

Can I enable website preview on all of the links in my web page?
i.e. when the user moves the mouse over any link in the page, I want to show a simple popup window which loads the page in link.

If it's important, I'm using Asp.net

Comment: Yes you can of course. I think the question you need to be asking is "how".

Comment: From a chrome users perspective, can I implement this for links on pages that I go to? I've seen some chrome addons like this, but I wonder about security.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use an `iframe` tag to display another page.

```
    <iframe src="http://www.example.com"></iframe>
```

Your HTML

```
 <a class="tiptext">A link
 <iframe class="description" src="http://www.example.com"></iframe>
 </a>
```

Your CSS

```
.tiptext {
    color:#069; 
    cursor:pointer;
}
.description {
    display:none;
    position:absolute;
    border:1px solid #000;
    width:400px;
    height:400px;
}
```

Your JS

```
$(".tiptext").mouseover(function() {
    $(this).children(".description").show();
}).mouseout(function() {
    $(this).children(".description").hide();
});
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/yboss/q29tP/

Comment: That works but I believe the browser will load the linked page every time, whether the user hovers or not.  Is there a way to have lazy page loading so that if no preview is shown, the linked page isn't fetched?